# Unsupported import

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I try to search this error across the web but I cannot find the solution. Any idea?

[image]

Regards,
Jimmy

Comment: you need to add the dependency of the following importa in your pom.xml

Comment: I can run the program. I have added it.

Comment: then clean and build your projects

Comment: Do this more than 10 times

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem, because IntelIJ is caching a lot of stuff. Your application may run with success in terminal, but IntelIJ may be stubborn to show you these errors.
This is common especially when you change between git branches with different versions of code.
What I usually do :

- I run maven clean command : mvn clean - to remove target folders
- after I press build and after again build Ctrl + F9. Important you must run build from IntelIJ **twice**

This is the fast solution and usually it works.
If the problem persists, I restart IntelIJ with **Invalidate Cache and Restart**.

Sometimes I delete .idea folder and reimport the project.

If this does not work as well I go for the longest solution:

```
mvn clean package
```

Usually it may have problems if you installed the project with mvn install, so I run the mentioned command to clear the installed version.
If this does not work as well I go and press reimport maven projects (the first button from the picture)

[image]

Hope it helps. It happens to me a lot as well. If you find another solution please let me know as well.

Comment: Actually, your answer does not help. But thanks for giving the direction.

Comment: Let me see if I understood your problem : is mvn clean package running with succes? Or the build fails?